# I am trying to find the sum of all the prime numbers below a certain number. if the initial number is prime we return it

Tags: python

```
def sumPrimes(num):
    sum = 0
    if num>1:
        for i in range(1, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                pass
            else: sum = sum + i
    return sum 

print(sumPrimes(3))
```

> i don't know why this isnt working pls help. I am trying to find the sum of all the prime numbers below a certain number. if the initial number is prime we return it.

Comment: your code is not working

Comment: oops it has to be i don't know why this isnt working not i don't know why this is working. Sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

Meaby It will help u

```
# Program to check if a number is prime or not

num = 407

# To take input from the user
#num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

# prime numbers are greater than 1
if num > 1:
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
       
# if input number is less than
# or equal to 1, it is not prime
else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this efficiently it's more complex than you might have imagined.

```
def genprime():
    yield 2
    D = {4:[2]}
    q = 3
    while True:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]
        q += 2



def isprime(n):
    if isinstance(n, int) and n >= 2:
        g = genprime()
        s = int(n ** 0.5)
        while True:
            d = next(g)
            if d > s:
                return True
            if n % d == 0:
                break
    return False

def sumPrimes(n):
    if isprime(n):
        return n
    g = genprime()
    sum = 0
    while (np := next(g)) < n:
        sum += np
    return sum

print(sumPrimes(12))
```

You'll need Python 3.7+ for this

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. If you want it to add 1 as a prime number change the second range to include 1.

```
def sumPrimes(num):
    sum = 0
    if num > 1:
       if all(num % n for n in range(2, num)) == True: #check of prime
           return num
       else:
           for i in range(2, num):
               if all(i % n for n in range(2, i)) == True: #if you want it to add the number 1 as a prime number change this range to range(1,i)
                   sum += i
               else:
                   continue
           return sum
```

Comment: I don't think 1 is ever a prime number ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_prime` to check if the number is prime in the loop:

```
import math
def is_prime(x):
    for num in range(2, int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1):
        if x % num == 0:
            return False
    return True

def sumPrimes(num):
    return sum([x for x in range(2,num) if is_prime(x)])
```

Comment: This will work but it's very inefficient because it carries out modulus operations with values that are not themselves prime - e.g., x % 4